# how do i consume net.tcp binding within web project?

Tags: c#, wcf, net.tcp

I'm working on a web application using mvc, we have already a service that does http binding, the client wants tcp binding for certain actions (not really sure why) but it's their requirement so i'm attempting to set up net.tcp binding, all references i am seeing to doing this involve a windows application and not a web application.

I guess my question has 2 parts, first can you run httpbinding and net.tcp binding at the same time through the same service/project.

secondly how would I consume the service through a webproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "Programming WCF Services" 
http://www.amazon.de/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric-ebook/dp/B0043D2DUK/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1408811647&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=programming+wcf+services+3d+edition

> Every service is associated with an address that defines where the service is, a binding
>   that defines how to communicate with the service, and a contract that defines what the
>   service does. This triumvirate governing the service is easy to remember as the ABC of
>   the service. WCF formalizes this relationship in the form of an endpoint. The endpoint
>   is the fusion of the address, contract, and binding.

So, in your case you'll need to define 2 endpoints for your service.
Example from the same book:

```
<service name = "MyService">
<endpoint
address = "http://localhost:8000/MyService"
binding = "wsHttpBinding"
contract = "IMyContract"
/>
<endpoint
address = "net.tcp://localhost:8001/MyService"
binding = "netTcpBinding"
contract = "IMyContract"
/>
<endpoint
address = "net.tcp://localhost:8002/MyService"
binding = "netTcpBinding"
contract = "IMyOtherContract"
/>
</service>
```

On the client side you'll need to "Add service reference" in VS and provide an address of the desired endpoint.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can set up both HTTP and a net.tcp endpoints (each of which will require it's own metadata exchange endpoints) within a service. More details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38fd2e58-85b3-42c6-955b-323cd0a922f2/wcf-binding-with-both-basichttpbinding-and-nettcpbinding-cant-access-http-endpoint?forum=wcf).

2) In your web application project, right click on `References` then click on `Add Service Reference`. In the dialog, copy the endpoint address of the net.tcp service. Enter the desired namespace and click ok.

Comment: This wont work as http binding doesnot support callbacks